# Google Translate and JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-translate

I have a website which is in French - I use Google translate to allow users to translate it into English which works great.

On the website there is a form to enter a town.  When the user starts typing the list is pulled from a javascript array and entered into a jquery array like this :

```
    strTowns = "LE BAR SUR LOUP, PARIS, LE FROMAGE,"
    arr = strError.split(",");
    $(function() {
        $( "#town" + pR ).autocomplete ( {
            source: arr

        });
        $( "#town" + pR ).autocomplete( "option", "minLength", 2 );
    });
```

this also works great.  However if the user has chosen to translate the site into English the google translator also translates my town list so that "LE FROMAGE" becomes "LE CHEESE" which is of course meaningless as "LE CHEESE" is not even a town.

I have spent hours trying to prevent this using  etc but to noavil.

Can anyone help ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's really no good solution to bad computer translations, other than to translate it yourself and provide an alternate website. [Apache servers can be set to automatically select a version of the site based on the browser](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html).

Comment: ok thanks but i wannt to prevent tranlation entirely.  in the jquery array i use the class=noTranslate etc but it doesn't get recognised...

Comment: The following would, probably, solve your problem: reorder your code, so that "autocomplete" function is called AFTER the translation is finished (for example, in translate callback function).